# db2 removing generated always on timestamp columns

Tags: db2

I have a Column UPDATE_TIME 
having the expression

```
 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP
```

how to remove the Generated always for Timestamps

I also tried

```
  db2 "alter table xxxx alter column UPDATE_TIME drop expression"
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76098/db2-removal-of-genrate-always-expression-on-timestamp-data-type

Answer (score 1):

Since it is defined as a `ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP`

You have to drop the column and re-add it.

Why would you want to do this in the first place?